# Chronological order to The End Times

Tags: suggested-order, warhammer-fantasy

[The End Times](http://1d4chan.org/wiki/The_End_Times) has begun in the Warhammer fantasy universe and I'm wondering is there any chronological order in which to read the novels?

The Black Library has released 9 books and I hate the idea of reading them out of order!

Comment: Are you talking about the novels or the books which come with the campaign books?

Comment: @Liath The novels

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Warhammer_Fantasy_novels#Warhammer:_The_End_Times has a list of four novels in the "end times" category. I assume the other 5 are unpublished. I would also further assume that reading them in order of publication would probably be the right order.

Comment: @Chris Reading them in the order of publication would make sense, but 3 of the 4 have the same release date.

Comment: @Daft: Oh yeah... I swear they didn't when I looked at the page first but in fairness I did just glance. Sorry but at least it helps with one. ;-)

Comment: @Chris no worries, I appreciate the link all the same.

Comment: @Chris You should post that as an answer, we need more fantasy questions!

Comment: @Liath: The problem is it doesn't answer the question. That link relates to four out of the nine books and doesn't give a relative order for three of them. It really is just a small part of the puzzle that may help somebody else willing to put more time into the research. If somebody else wants to convert it to an answer they are welcome to, I just don't feel it sufficiently answers the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm adding the dates as they appear in each book (when possible).

I'm also adding the Archaon older books. I deeply recommend starting the adventure with them.

Also, each *"The End Times - XX"* book should be read together with its corresponding novel, since it adds extra information to the novel (i.e. battles, pre and post novel events, characters info and the like).

- Archaon, Everchosen                 *(2390 - )*
- Archaon, Lord of Chaos              *( - 2519)*
- QR: Sigmar's Blood
- QR: The Bone Cage
- QR: With Ice and Sword
- (A) The Return of Nagash                *(late sum 2522 - erl wint 2524)*
- (A) The End Times I: Nagash Part 1
- Gotrek & Felix: Kinslayer           *(aut 2524 - erl spg 2525)*
- QR: Marienburg's Stand              *(erl wint 2525 - erl wint 2525)*
- (B) The Fall of Altdorf                 *(late wint 2524 - erl wint 2525)*
- (B) The End Times II: Glottkin Part 1   *(spg 2525 - aut 2525)*
- QR: The Siege of Naggarond          *(223 - )*
- QR: Bride of Khaine                 *(223 - )*
- Deathblade                          *(wint 2523 - aut 2524)*
- (C) The End Times III: Khaine Part 1    *(wint 2524 - wint 2526)*
- (C) The Curse of Khaine
- (D) The Rise of the Horned Rat          *(aut 2523 - aut 2527)*
- (D) The End Times IV: Thanquol Part 1   *(aut 2523 - aut 2527)*
- QR: Gotrek & Felix: Rememberers     *(wint 2526 - wint 2526)*
- Gotrek & Felix: Slayer              *(erl spg 2527 - erl sum 2527)*
- (E) The End Times V: Archaon Part 1     *(spg 2528 - aut 2528)*
- (E) Lord of the End Times               *(aut 2527 - aut 2528)*

Edit:
QR means "Quick read". These are short stories that I believe have only been released digitally.
I have also added matching letters to the ones that should be read together.

Comment: Could you perhaps expand on your answer? I really want to read these but I don't understand a couple of things. You said "Also, each "The End Times - XX" book should be read together with its corresponding novel, since it adds extra information to the novel (i.e. battles, pre and post novel events, characters info and the like)." - could you give me an example of which book should be read with which novel?

Some of the other titles you listed start with "QR" - what does that mean?

Comment: There you go. I'm sorry for the delay. I have bought  Total War: Warhammer and I have resumed the reading. Hope to finish with all the books one day hehhe.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell and have read the order goes like this:

1. Sigmar's Blood
2. The Bone Cage
3. Return of Nagash
4. End Times I: Nagash Part 1
5. Gotrek & Felix: Kinslayer
6. End Times II: Glottkin Part 1
7. QR: Marienburg's Stand
8. The Fall of Altdorf
9. QR: The Siege of Naggarond
10. QR: Bride of Khaine
11. The End Times III: Khaine Part 1
12. Deathblade
13. The Curse of Khaine
14. Rise of the Horned Rat
15. End Times IV: Thanquol Part 1
16. QR: Gotrek & Felix: Rememberers
17. QR: With Ice and Sword
18. End Times V: Archaon Part 1
19. Gotrek & Felix: Slayer
20. Lord of the End Times

I'm not completely sure, as I've read only the first few, but that's how I have understood it and is the order I will read it. There are also a few Quick-Reads (QR) included in there, not quite sure about where those belong as they are not part of the main storyline but rather one-off side stories.

Hope this is still relevant and that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I emailed The Black Library for a list of The End Times books in chronological order, and they replied with this:

> Thank you for your email. The Chronological order to read the End Times Novels is.
>
> Sigmar's Blood
> Kinslayer
> Rise of Nagash
> Fall of Altdorf
> Deathblade
> Curse of Khaine
> The Rise of the Horned Rat

The order is slightly different, but the accepted answer above covers many more novels and novellas.

**UPDATE**

So it would appear the the email I received from The Black Library actually contradicts how the novels are [now listed on their own website](http://www.blacklibrary.com/Home/endtimes.html).

Having read the majority of them at this stage, I can tell you this new list is correct.